# Sintered or Semi-metallic brake pads,which one is the best choice for my 03 ,Polaris Ranger 2x4 Series?

Tags: brakes, polaris

My brake pads were worn out ,need new ones.From the blog,

> Semi Metallic ,NAO, Low-Metallic NAO ,Ceramic And Sintered Brake Pads :What’s the advantage and disadvantage and how to chose correct material brake pads ?

know different material pads:
Like sintered ,semi-metallic and so on.
Which one is best choice for my 03 ,Polaris Ranger 2x4 Series. Need durable pads and no squeak after install it as well as not create a lot of dust.Any advice ?

Comment: Answrs to this question may be largely opinion-based.  Pad quality is a huge factor beyond mere material.  The "squeak" portion can easily be solved by using good full ceramic pads, and no matter what pad material you choose, always liberally apply the sticky gooey (typically blue) spray before assembly.

Comment: What sort of driving do you do, normal everyday or do you do lots of hard braking which might cause fade?

Comment: Commuting,going out on weekend ,so on.Bought on the first half of 2017,have put on 50000 miles.

Comment: You put 50K miles on a Polaris Ranger UTV in half a year??  I find that implausible, unless I'm missing something.  If I'm wrong, Bravo!

Comment: so you bought the car in 2017 and not the pads, right?

Answer (score 1):

Sintered pads are great.
Recently,I replaced the sintered rear pads for my Honda, TRX 450 R bought it from [online here.](https://www.hexautoparts.com/foreverunmoto-sintered-brake-pads-at185-at373-three-pairs-for-front-and-rear.html)

The rear pads fit well and perform well on rainy weather. I just keep the front ones as a spare.